# Android System Image

Tags: android

I downloaded latest Eclipse ADT for Android but did not find any emulator embedded. 
I guess I have to put a system image in the SDK Manager. My internet is continuously getting on getting connection refused. Error, and I am chosing the following link to go with

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/6588/how-to-install-android-sdk-without-internet-connection/

How do I know which System Image I need?

Answer (score 0):

The version you need depends on the target version your app will be designed for.
I recommend that you choose a version that is wide spread and running on most devices, so you will have the biggest possible customer coverage.

See also:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history
- http://www.android.com/history/
- http://www.zdnet.com/kitkat-market-share-grows-to-2-5-percent-7000027097/

And if you decide not to go with eclipse, I recommend you Android Studio from Google:
https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html